# What is a good way for private hosting of a (django) website?

Tags: django, networking

Let's say I have created a website using the django framework.

I would like to to host it and access the website by my own AND by certain people that I choose. I don't want to host it on a public domain on the internet.

What I can do:

- Host the website on a local computer (let's say a Raspberry Pi with RaspbianOS) with a certain IP address and port
- Access the website from anywhere using VPN

Now I do not like the VPN solution as I also have other devices in my network. I want certain people to be able to access the website but I don't want them in my network.

What is a good way to achieve what I want or is there maybe even a way?

Comment: Search for Wireguard I think can help you

Comment: Technically if the server is accessible by some people, it means it is accessible by everone on the web. You can however use a login system or block all connections on a server using a firewall (except for the IP address that you would allow).

Comment: Seconded @FrédéricPerron. Alternatively if you buy a domain name and set the DNS to point to your home IP (or use a dynamic DNS service such as noip.com) you can then set up a proxy service such as Apache with password protected access to the site (make sure you implement HTTPS on any site where you will be sending passwords in plaintext to the server via the internet).

It is good practice to set up a DMZ on your home network for applications like this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29. Basically a separate subnet for all of your hosts that have internet facing ports.

Comment: Mmh Frederics answer kind of sounds complicated to me tbh. Isn't there a simpler solution?